# FontForge: how to blend cursive letters?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-forge

I'm working on a shorthand font, which requires anchoring each letter to the next because of the absence of any baseline. When I check my anchors though, I see that the letters are properly placed relative to each others, but they don't blend together. Instead the tip of the second letter is superimposed on the end tip of the first one, like this where you can see a white line between the curved shape and the adjacent round shape.

[image]